# Plot selection of columns from large arrays into one graph, with fortran and gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, multiple-columns

I have and array with 69 rows and 99 columns and one with 43 rows and 99 columns. I want to plot selected columns from both arrays into one graph.

```
Write(10,'(A,9(I3,A))') 'plot "xydata1.dat" using ',Index1+1,':1 with '//trim(Layout1)//' title "'//TRIM(graph_title1)//'", etc.
```

The write is to a gnuplot command file which is later called by my fortran program. Index1 and Layout1 are put in the subroutine call in my main program so that the subroutine can be used multiple times. Index1 is what is used to determine which column is plotted and the graph_title. Layout1 is based on input into the subroutine call and determines. Up till and including 4 lines this works perfectly but with more the plot type isn't recognized anymore.
For one file and columns that are next to each other or regular organized, the following works.

```
Write(10,'(A)') 'plot for [n=1,9] "xydata1.dat" using (column(n+1)):1 with lines ls (10+n) title columnheader(n+1)'
```

However I might want to plot column 1,2,5,9 and a few from the second array in another data file, this is something I can't get to work.

Please let me know if and how this can be done.

Comment: Are you using Linux as OS?

Comment: I'm not really sure what the issue is - is it your data file, the Fortran program that you use to generate the gnuplot script, or is it the gnuplot script itself? For your last point, you can select specific values of n: `plot for [n in "1 2 5 9"] ...`

Comment: Thanks Miguel, the code you provided was exactly what I was looking for. I didn't know that was possible, what I got was that it would print 3,4,6,7,8 as well as what I wanted. For the record I am using windows as OS.